# Custom Vector Template - Strings

Tags: c++, string, templates, vector

I am attempting to read in a list of strings from the keyboard to a custom vector template that I wrote, however for some unknown reason, the program ALWAYS crashes after the second or third input when I attempt to write to or read the vector object.

Note: The entire point of the assignment is to write your own custom vector class and I am not allowed to use any feature provided by the C++ STL, such as arrays.

edit: Everything works without fault if I make it an int or char vector, but it needs to do all 3.

edit: It has become pretty obvious that my lecturer is trying to force us to do this in some sort of round about messed up way that is no where near good coding practice. Thanks for the help guys, but I don't think im going to get anywhere here because you are all telling me the right thing to do, and its clear my lecturer doesnt want the right thing, he wants what he has decided is the right thing.

Comment: NEVER use malloc or free. If you reupload code using new and delete instead people will help you...

Comment: Why are you mixing C and C++ memory management, e.g. calling `delete []` on something previously allocated with `malloc` ???

Comment: Never mix `new/delete` with `malloc/free/realloc`. And, `malloc/free/realloc` on non-POD types yields undefined behaviour. Your code is dangerous.

Comment: Probably he doesn,t want you to use stl blindingly? He just want's you to try to implement something similar? It's hard, but leads you to a better understanding of how it is done and why. He's not necessarily stupid. :) I don't see your code, so I'm not so sure whether I understood your question correctly. As far as I know, If you don't want to implement your own C++ :) there is no way to construct an object on top of a chunk of uninitialized memory other than new or placement new operator call, which leads to a corresponding Ctor call.

Answer (score 3):

Use `new` and `delete[]` instead of `malloc` and `free`. Why?

- `new` and `delete` call constructors and destructors of created objects, so for example

  ```
  string * str = new string("foo");
  ```

  will create object of type string on heap, and return pointer to it, and

  ```
  delete str;
  ```

  will call its destructor, and then free the memory.
- `malloc` and `free` are C's memory management functions, so they have no idea about
  constructors and destructors. All they do is take and return chunk of memory from the      heap,
  so if you try to:

  ```
  string * str = (string*) malloc(sizeof(string));
  ```

  you will get just uninitialized chunk of memory as big as string object.  **No constructors are called**. It can (and in most cases will) cause errors, because proper operation of created object most likely will depend of proper intialization (your `myvector` is a good example). Situation with `free` is symmetric.

Comment: I'd consider upvoting this if you would have explained *why* `new` and `delete[]` should be used.

Comment: I am not allowed to use new. New implies an array, and im not allowed to use any STL containers supplied by C++

Comment: C++ arrays are not a part of STL

Comment: if arrays are not part of STL, then why is it listed here as one http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

My lecturer has said no arrays, so is there any way to get malloc and strings to work together?

Comment: Maybe add a remark that using `malloc/free` on non-POD types yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does anyone have some sort of official link that states that array=new int[maxsize]; has nothing to do with the STL so when he fails me I have a backup?

Comment: on page you linked, array is listed as part of C++11 standard, and it's not a plain array like in C (which is created by new).

Answer (score 2):

When allocating memory for the elements you cannot use `malloc` for non-POD types - you need to call constructor for such type by using `new`. E.g. you cannot `malloc` memory for a `std::string` object and then use `operator=` to copy string (in whatever magical way) to returned address.

Answer (score 0):

Never mix `new/delete` with `malloc/free/realloc`. And, `malloc/free/realloc` on non-POD types (like `std::string`) yields undefined behaviour. Your code is dangerous and has no defined runtime behaviour.

<sup>If your boss insists on using them, try to teach him about the true way of C++, or accept that your applications will at one day crash (and you will have a *horrible* time tracking down the bugs), or quit the job, or, if you have big nuts, go to your bosses boss and tell him</sup>

Further, you have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

This is not standard C++ if you are refering to `std::string`. Use

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
```

And even further: You state in comments that you are not allowed to use standard containers. Yet you seem to use `std::string`, which is a container.

Yet another thing: `using namespace std;` in a header is really bad practice and sooner or later leads to name conflicts that are hard to debug.

Let me also reiterate:
**Using `new/malloc/realloc` on non-POD types means that your program loses any defined behaviour. It is like the horizon of a blackhole.`**

Comment: I wish it was a job, this is for uni. I honestly dont understand why he is asking us to do it in this way, but he is.

Comment: Then he is dangerously wrong and might be the cause for catastrophes like crashing space shuttles. He shouldn't be there, he is an idiot, because he stopped learning C++ at some point and now acts like a C++ teacher.